# magento show all discount coupons in shopping cart

Tags: magento, discount, coupon

```
    <?php $rulesCollection = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection();
            $i=1;
            $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
            $totalPrice = 0;  
            foreach($items as $item) {
            $totalPrice+=$item->getPrice();
            }
            $coll = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load();
            echo '<div class=vip_test>';
            foreach($coll as $rule){
            $productDetail = $rule->afterLoad();
            $discountAmount = $productDetail['discount_amount'];
            echo "<div class=ssk><span> You Save : </span>".$totalAmount =  $totalPrice-($discountAmount/100*$totalPrice)."</div>";
          $ruleID = $productDetail['rule_id'];
           } 
            foreach($rulesCollection as $rule){
           $coupon = $rule->getCode();
            $couponName = $rule->getName()

           ?>
```

In Magento, with this I am getting only the coupon code and coupon name. I want to display if there is any coupon code for particular product in shopping cart, in front of coupon  - its showing the saving amount. Is it possible or not? Am I doing Wrong? please help me

Comment: I think there is a long way for you to travel to reach your solution. It cant be as simple as you mentioned your requirement

Comment: then, how can we do this? please help me.

Comment: Magento only applies one coupon code at a time - kind of at cross purposes as the customers will be po'd when they find they can't use multiples.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get the collection of products which are in your cart. Then you need to check if there are any active coupons in catalog price rules or shopping cart price rules for the products which are in your cart. If all the above conditions becomes true then you need to display the coupon code of it.

On the next side, you need to calculate the difference amount of it and also you need to display if the user increases his quantity then the savings amount value also has to be increased.

Comment: $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
    
}        by this code i can get all items in cart but how can i check if there are any coupons on them